# How can I resolve datatables library issue in my project?

Tags: c#, datatables

I create a project with a GridView and I had datatables library in my project.
I create a page `test` which is in a `master` page, this `master` page already have the cdn

```
<script src="Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="Content/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but in my `test` page when I try to use my library I have this error

> ```
> raygun.js:257
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
> at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:90)
> at Function.each (jquery.js:374)
> at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js:139)
> at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:90)
> at Function.each (jquery.js:374)
> at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js:139)
> at n.fn.init.m [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:82)
> at n.fn.init.h.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:167)
> at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (TestSoleyne.aspx:47697)
> at HTMLDocument.b (raygun.js:61)
> ```

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContenuPage" runat="Server">

    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#Grid').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "pagingType" : "first_last_numbers",
                "searching": true,
                "lengthMenu": [20, 50, 100],
                "pageLength" : 20
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-condensed" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="Grid_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Id"/>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fullname">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("lastname") + " " + Eval("firstname") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I think it may comes from the error so I don't have the pagination, the search input and the basic css of the table is not modify.

Someone have any idea how can I resolve my issue ?

Moreover, I create a html table and it works on it.

Comment: Did you verify that all your scripts are loaded successfully with no errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the id of my datatable.I have a master page so I have to put the id of my master page with the id of my my element.

so my id was `#master_page_id_Grid`

***BEFORE***

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#Grid').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

**AFTER**

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#master_page_id_Grid').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```